# I keep getting the following error message -TypeError: Todo.createDocument is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Every time I run the following command:

```
-$ curl -X POST -d '{ "text": "Item something", "done": true }' --header "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:3000/todos
```

I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Todo.createDocument is not a function

## app.js

```
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

const router = express.Router();

const bodyParse = require('body-parser');

const Todo = require('./todo');

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

router.route('/todos')
  .get((req, res) => {
    Todo.all(function(data){
      console.log('Retrieving all Todos');
      res.json(data);
    })

  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    Todo.createDocument(req.body, function(data){
      console.log('Todo created with id ${data._id}');
      res.json(data);
    })
  })


app.use('/', router);

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 
${port}!'));
```

## console log

```
TypeError: Todo.createDocument is not a function
    at router.route.get.post (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/app.js:20:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at next (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/robbrown/node-todo-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Here is my todo.js file I hope someone can help me figure this out. I have been trying to find the answer for the past few days. For some reason SO will not let me add this?? Error message post is mostly code.

## todo.js ##

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParse: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function(){
  console.log('Connected to MongoDb!');
});

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  done: Boolean
})

todoSchema.statics.createDocumnent = function(params, callback){
  return Todo.create({ text: params.text, done: params.done },
    function (err, todo) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      callback(todo);
    }
  )
}
todoSchema.statics.all = function(callback){
  return Todo.find({}, function(err, todos){
    callback({ todos: todos });
  })
}
const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);

module.exports = Todo;
```

Comment: It says `Todo.createElement` is not a function. But the code u shared doesn't actually show any info about Todo. Please share with us the code in `todo.js`

Comment: Well, show the code of the `todo` module.It should be in a `todo.js` file, residing in the same directory as `app.js`.  Then we will see, whether it contains a `createDocument` method. Probably, it doesn't, because that's what the error message says.

Answer (score -1):

> post((req, res) => {
>      Todo.createDocument(req.body, function(data){
>        console.log('Todo created with id ${data._id}');
>        res.json(data);
>      })
>    })

The issue is here, when you call on `createDocument()` function. The function `createDocument` is not found within your `Todo` class.

Now,  I am not able to see what is the `Todo` class here but if it inherits methods from a parent class (ie. a DOMImplementation class) then check your inherit reference or add the `createDocument` function inside your `Todo` class.

Comment: You are doing way to much interpretation and guessing on the information, the OP gave. The only thing, we know for sure right now: there is a module `Todo` which is supposed to have a `createDocument` method, but doesn't.

Comment: You are absolutely right but it does help since I am not able to comment yet and the other guys commenting are just asking for `Todo` code. If that class inherits methods then the method createDocument should be available for reference from this inheriting class even though it is not defined within the class itself. I have given him pointers on possible solutions based on available information. I will modify my answer to be less assumptive.